# Celery max_tasks_per_child setting is not restarting the worker

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery

Failing on both Celery 4.4.7 and 5.0.2.

My task is leaking a substantial amount of memory.
I'd like to restart the worker after each task.
I'm starting the celery in a no concurrency mode `--concurrency=1` or/and `-P solo` as the memory used in a single task might be close to the total system memory.

I tried to set the `worker_max_tasks_per_child = 1` in the `celeryconfig.py` and `--max-tasks-per-child=1` in CLI, but the worker is not restarting.

Comment: That setting does not configure Celery worker to restart, but to spawn a new _worker-process_ after N tasks. I guess the behaviour also depends on the type of concurrency you use...

Comment: There is no concurrency. The process is big and requires GPU. So `--concurrency 1 -P solo`

Comment: I never used _solo_ so far... With prefork concurrency it works as expected. Maybe it is handled differently in your case. I would assume with _solo_ there are no worker-processes so therefore worker_max_tasks_per_child is ignored as, guess what, there is no "child" process! :) Try without using solo and concurrency set to 1. That is almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, [the setting](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#max-tasks-per-child-setting) is not honored since you specified the pool configuration of your worker as 'solo'. It works only if your configuration is 'prefork'. If you start the worker with the changed configuration, you should be able to see the change. I used the option to prevent memory leak issue of tensorflow since it does not return the reserved memory till the process terminates, which was big problem in my application. I also didn't realize why the setting didn't work till see the limit from the link.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that celery workers don't terminate after a task as ended. I would try using [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) at the end of your task, that way the process will exit and `systemd` or any other service in charge of your processes will bring it back up.

But the real solution should be to write a code with no memory leaks